# edge shade based on decreasing edge weights

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I'm trying to colour edges and create a matching linear colour scale with 0 as light gray and 1 as black using `colorRampPalette`. However, since I cannot rearrange the edge sequence `E(g)` based on decreasing `E(g)$weights` to make it match the linear scale, the graph turns out wrong.

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=4)
mat[2,1] <- 0.5
mat[3,4] <- 0.9
mat[3,1] <- 0.1
mat[4,2] <- 0.3

require(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(mat, mode="directed", diag=F, weighted = T)
E(g)$arrow.width <- 1.3
E(g)$arrow.size <- 0.4

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

plot(g, layout=layout.circle, edge.width=E(g)$weight*5, edge.color="black")

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "lightgray"))
my.palette <- rev(colfunc(length(E(g)$weight)))
E(g)$color <- my.palette
plot(g, layout=layout.circle)

#scale
plot(y=sort(E(g)$weight),x=rep(1,length(E(g)$weight)),col=rev(colfunc(length(E(g)$weight[order(E(g)$weight)]))),main="strength",pch=19,cex=3,xaxt="n",ann=T,bty="n",ylim=0:1)
```

I would like to match the edge sequence to the ordered weights, something like

```
E(g) <- E(g)[order(E(g)$weight,decreasing = T)]
```

but that does not work. Also, just ordering the weights does not change the edge sequence and hence the graph turns out incorrect.

Below is the two example graphs and the scale. Clearly the edge shade in the latter graph does not correspond to the edge thickness in the former which is what I want. The scale corresponds to the edge shading in the latter graph.

[image]

Any advice is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do not reorder the edges, reorder the colors.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make Gabor's comment explicit, you need to order the colors to match the order of edges in igraph. That is, replace the line:

`E(g)$color <- my.palette`

with:

`E(g)$color <- my.palette[rev(order(E(g)$weight))]`

Note the `rev` is only necessary because of the `rev` in the line before and both can be removed.